# How to read value from App.config (not .net core app) in DBContext (which is entity framework core)

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, .net-core

I'm using my old application (Standard .net framework wpf app) with new entity framework core.

[image]
I've set up connection to database by hardcoding connection string here:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
   optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"server=baaa;database=baaa;User=saaa;Password=xsaa1;");
}
```

But I would like to move my connection string to App.config or somewhere else and read it from there instead of keeping it hardcoded.

Since my WPF app is not .net core WPF app I can't use DI to write something like this:

```
IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                .Build();
```

So question is how to read connection string from my old WPF (.NET FRAMEWORK) App in DbContect of entity framework core?

Thanks

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Microsoft's ConfigurationManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.configurationmanager?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1)
It exists both in .net core and .net framework.
at .net core you can add simply from nuget, and at .framework just add the system.configuration dll

read app-setting:

```
 var version=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["APP_SETTING_KEY"].ConnectionString;
```

read connection string:

```
 var cs =ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["YOUR_CS_KEY"].ConnectionString;
```

Comment: DbContext is in separated project so i'm not sure if it's aware of appsettings? since app config file is in another project (WPF project) ?

Comment: check for my edit please. I've posted an image of structure there.

Comment: but since that the project is link into your main WPF one, it should know to use it's configuration. did you give it a try?